# Finding the eigenvalue of F(V)=(V⋅W)W+V where W=(1 , 1 , 2) and f:R^3 → R^3

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear algebra test in 3 days and there was this problem that i was having difficulties with! Found this in some of the practice quizzes in my university website! So the Problem goes like this :

Let **W=(1 , 1 , 2)**.Let R^3 be the endomorphism defined by: **V** ∈ **R^3** such that **F(V)=(V⋅W)W+V**
The answer to this problem is : ""**W** is an eigenvector of eigenvalue 7""

Here is a picture of the problem as well: [image: The poblem]

Comment: Please read the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question

Comment: @Laufen i don't understand !

Comment: Please show your attempts. What have you done so far? Per the Meta Read, "by providing a context, you help the potential responders to your question give you the best help you need."

Comment: What do you get after plugging in w into f(.)?

Comment: @Laufen That's the reason i'm posting it here! I don't know how to begin! If there is a chance you can drop any hints as how to proceed! Then i'll try to solve it myself

Comment: @Laufen nevermind i think i did it! Correct me if im wrong but what i did was:  I multiplied w by w first and i got 6 so we have 6*V + V so we have 7V which is of the type λV so therefore 7 is an eigenvalue right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\underline w=(1,1,2)$ and given your map $F:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$, you simply have to calculate the image of the vector.
$$F(\underline w)=(\underline w\cdot\underline w)\underline w+\underline w=\lVert \underline w\rVert^2\underline w+\underline w=(1^2+1^2+2^2)\underline w+\underline w=6\underline w+\underline w=7\underline w$$.
For definition, the eigenvalue $\lambda$ associated to the vector $\underline w$ is equal to $7$, since $\underline w\overset{F}{\mapsto}7\underline w$.

Comment: @Varja so for all the types of "vector functions" like this one where you have a given vector like W you just compute f(W) right?

Comment: Yep. For definition $\underline v\in V$ is an eigenvector for a map $F$ if $\exists\lambda\in\mathbb K$ such that $F(\underline v)=\lambda \underline v$.